# Cannot have public member 'name'

Tags: playframework

I'm using JDK 7 and testing Play! 1.2.4. I was creating a test class with a public member called 'name' and got the exception that my class was overriding final method 'getName':

```
public class DummyClass extends Thread {
    public String name;
    ...
}
```

This class is not really part of the "framework" itself: it is a Thread that receives info from a Socket and stores it in a Database through Play! JPA object (from the "models" package).
My application is not a full "Web app" but has some parts which should be accessed through a browser (typically: configuration, simple Database search, ...). It is running a @OnApplicationStart Job which launches Threads, Sockets, saves files, ...

I'm guessing Play! automatically generates getters and setters but it looks like it is also changing my own classes.

I'm not sure if this is a "bug" of the framework or if I just misunderstood the concept and need to change a few things (at least, renaming 'name' into 'dummyName' does the trick! :))?

Here is the Stack trace:

```
play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:244)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:286)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.deepgray.acq.Acquisition overrides final method getName.()Ljava/lang/String;
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:166)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:84)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClasses.java:67)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:455)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.endTag(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:342)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.generate(TemplateCompiler.java:93)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:15)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.compile(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:41)
        at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:28)
        at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:82)
        at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:162)
        at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:190)
        at play.mvc.Router.parse(Router.java:164)
        at play.mvc.Router.load(Router.java:48)
        at play.mvc.Router.detectChanges(Router.java:219)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem you have here is that you have a public member, which the play 'magic' is generating setters and getters for you.

Simply changing the member name will solve your issue. I don't think this is a bug, because Play expects to enhance these classes. I am not sure if it should be restricted to certain packages, because it is a general expectation that all public members are made accessible in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using my own threads. Play does a lot of "magic" to enhance models, add transactions and jpa capabilities.

I think the preferred way to approach this would be to have a job listen to a socket. Jobs are automatically enhanced with jap support and transactions, which makes it easy to save your data once received.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing. I wanted to use Play! just to easily offer my application some Web capabilities. The downside is that it has to be fully developped under the framework. Hopefully I can start (a) Job(s) in which my application runs but I consider this a bad use of Play!...

Answer (score 0):

Have you annotated DummyClass with any Play/JPA Annotations?

If not, this is a bug and should be reported on the issue tracker.

Comment: No, the `DummyClass` is a POJO, not even in any Play package (it is in one of my com.xxx package).